# How can I select the element of html file (except first and last) using DOM and manipulate it?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-manipulation, html-manipulation

[image]

Here i want to select the second LI of UL using DOM and mainuplate it , i know how to select first and last element but i am not able to select second ,third and so on element . How to do it?

[image]
I want to change the "second" written on the html page(see picture 2 below) to my name using DOM.

Answer (score 4):

```
let list = document.querySelector("ul").querySelectorAll("li");

for(let i = 1; i < list.length - 2; i++){
     list[i].doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use querySelectAll and length proprety like this:

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li');
el[el.length-2].textContent="Shubham Kandpal";
```

or using jquery's eq() method like this:

```
$("ul > li").eq(-1).text("Shubham Kandpal");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nth-child

```
ul > li:nth-child(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this javascript selector to select the Second (LI) option.

`document.querySelector('ul li:nth-child(2)')`

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way, besides querySelector, is by adding a class or an Id and getting it:

Adding using a class

```js
function myFunction() {
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName("className");
  x[1].textContent = "Whatever you want to name it now"; 
  // 1 because it is the second position
}
```

or by id

```js
function myFunction() {
  let x = document.getElementById("idName");
  x.innerHTML = "Whatever you want to name it now"; 
  // You can also use innerHtml to change the text
}
```

Comment: I believe it should be `x.innerHTML` instead of `x[1].innerHTML` when querying by id. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: Yes! Thank you! and I am sorry.